# Как правильно переназначить методы place, pack и grid в составе класса?

Tags: python

как правильно переназначить методы place, pack и grid в составе класса?
 Нужно сделать так, чтобы параметры которые не заданы применялись те, которые по умолчанию стоят в исходных методах place, pack и grid.

Мой пример (но я не уверен в правильности):

```
def place(self, x=None, y=None):
    self.canvas.place(x=x, y=y)

def pack(self, fill=None, expand=None, side=None, anchor=None, padx=None, pady=None):
    self.canvas.pack(fill=fill, expand=expand, side=side, anchor=anchor, padx=padx,  pady=pady)

def grid(self, row=None, column=None, columnspan=None, sticky=None, rowspan=None, padx=None, pady=None):
    self.canvas.grid(row=row, column=column, columnspan=columnspan, sticky=sticky, rowspan=rowspan, padx=padx, pady=pady)
```

Может так лучше?:

```
def place(self, *args):
    self.canvas.place(*args)

def pack(self,  *args):
    self.canvas.pack(*args)

def grid(self, *args):
    self.canvas.grid(*args)
```

Comment: Оно и так и так работает нормально, выглядит, как вопрос вкуса. Но, я бы предпочел второй вариант, где все компактно и удобно, с этого стоит начинать. Если бы это стало приводить к каким-то проблемам - постепенно это могло бы преобразоваться в первый вариант. Зависит от конкретных обстоятельств.

Comment: @ mrEvgenX, вот как раз в итоге со 2 вариантом и возникают проблемы...

Comment: В вопросе про них ни слова. Если код запускается ровно так, как написан в вопросе, то понятно какие проблемы и ответ insolor все должен решить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно пробросить все аргументы метода - и позиционные (просто перечисляемые через запятую), и именованные (передаваемые с указанием имени аргумента, например `row=3`) - в вызов другого метода, нужно принять и передать и `*args`, и `**kwargs`:

```
def some_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
    some_object.some_other_method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: спасибо за совет, еще не пробовал, но логично, чуть позже попробую.